# How do I calculate the number of permutations of a set of 5 double sided cards?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

If I have say 5 double sided cards how do I work out the number of permutations.
I know 5 single side cards is 5! (5×4×3×2×1) But if each card has an a and b side with an equal chance of either side what is the formula.

Answer (score 0):

There are $5!$ to arrange the cards.  For each of the five cards, there are two ways to choose the side which faces up. Hence, there are $5!2^5$ possible permutations of the cards if all ten sides are distinct.

Comment: Cool thank you very much. I got as far as "something like 5!×2..."